# Object.values seems not to work in enum type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, enums, enumeration

I have this enum defined in my app:

```
export enum Status {
    BOOKED = 'B',
    FREE = 'F',
}
```

and I add this message on the console

```
console.log ('<------------------------------------>');
        console.log (code.value);
        console.log (Object.values(Status));
        console.log (code.value in Object.values(Status));
        console.log ('<------------------------------------>');

 <------------------------------------>
```

and I see this on the console, code.value is not included in the enum; I should see true

```
    B
    [ 'B', 'F' ]
   false
```

Comment: See what `in` is for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `array.include()` to check if an array contain a value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```js
const values = Object.values(Status);
console.log(values.includes(code.value));
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but I have the error: S2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Status'.

Comment: You may have to cast the enum to a plain array first: `Object.values<string>(Status as {}).includes(code.value)`

Comment: @SandroRey `code.value` is supposed to be of type string. If this is not the case, it may be better to do `values.includes(code.value as Status)`.

Answer (score -1):

You have this object

```
export enum Status {
    BOOKED = 'B',
    FREE = 'F',
}
```

`Object.values(Status)` will give you `[ 'B', 'F' ]` which is expected

Read this for more info -

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop. (The only difference is that a for...in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values